# Ordenar array de cadena alfabeticamente

Tags: java, array

se trata de un metodo que ordenen un array de cadena mediante un algoritmo, pero al parecer el codigo que uso muestra un error en la comparacion del if

```
public void ordenar (Array3 a) {
    String buffer = null;
    int i =0;
    while ( i< a.getArreglo().length) {
        int j=0;
        while (j<i) {
            if (a.getArreglo(i)<a.getArreglo(j)) {
                buffer = a.getArreglo(j);
                a.setArreglo(j,a.getArreglo(i));
                a.setArreglo(i,buffer);
            }
            j++;
        }
    i++;
    }


}
```

Edito: lo siento por ser poco claro, soy bastante nuevo en esto, el error que marca es "The operator < is undefined for the argument type(s) java.lang.String"
lo siento si no pongo todo el programa, pero se me hace muy extenso.

Comment: "Muesra un error en la comparación del if", no es la mejor descripción del problema. ¿Qué error específicamente _muestra_? ¿en qué momento se muestra el error?. Por favor lee [¿Cómo elaboro una buena pregunta?](https://es.stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). Un saludo.

Comment: Que error te da en el if? Como te ha dicho el compañero en el comentario anterior, hace falta que amplies algo más tu pregunta.

Comment: Tu problema es que estás intentando comparar 2 string viendo si uno es mayor que el otro... y eso con strings... no se hace así. Tienes que utilizar el método compareTo de la clase String: https://www.tutorialspoint.com/java/java_string_compareto.htm

Answer (score 1):

Este es el clásico ordenamiento por el método burbuja:

Utiliza en tu IF `compareToIgnoreCase` para poder comparar los valores del arreglo por cada ciclo for y determinar las posiciones de estos:

```
if(vector[i].compareToIgnoreCase(vector[j]) < 0)


//Clase MAIN

//paquetes para la lectura de las cadenas a ingresar en el vector
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;

public class Main {
   public static void main(String[] args){
      //un objeto bufferedreader que recibe como parámetro un inputstreamreader para almacenar cada entrada que pidamos al usuario al vector.
      BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader (new InputStreamReader (System.in));

      try{
         //contador para llevar el control de las cadenas a ingresar
         int contador = 0;
         //vector de 6 posiciones tipo string
         String []vector = new String[6];
         //instanciamos un objeto de la clase burbuja
         Burbuja obj = new Burbuja(vector);
         //mientras el contador sea diferente de 6, seguimos pidiendo el ingreso de una nueva cadena
         while (contador != 6){
            //solicitud de la cadena
            System.out.println("Ingresa una cadena: ");
            //la posición n del vector será igual a la posición según contador y según la cadena que se lea en la petición anterior
            vector[contador] = in.readLine();
            //aumentamos el contador en uno
            contador++;
         }
         //del objeto instanciado de la clase burbuja invocamos el método ordenar
         obj.ordenar();
         //del objeto instanciado de la clase burbuja invocamos el método mostrar
         obj.mostrar();
      }catch(Exception e){
         System.out.println("Error: " + e);
      }
   }
}


//Clase Burbuja

public class Burbuja{
   un vector de tipo string
   private String vector[];

   //constructor
   public Burbuja(String vector[]){
      this.vector = vector;
   }

   //método ordenar
   public void ordenar(){
      //primer ciclo para recorrer el vector
      for(int i = 0; i < vector.length; i++){
         //segundo ciclo para recorerr el vector y verificar que el valor de i en el primer ciclo sea diferente al valor de j de este segundo ciclo
         for(int j = 0; j < vector.length && i != j; j++){
            //comparamos las posiciones de cada ciclo para saber que valor va alfabéticamente antes que el otro
            if(vector[i].compareToIgnoreCase(vector[j]) < 0){
               //variable auxiliar para guardar el valor de i
               String aux = vector[i];
               //cambio de posiciones
               vector[i] = vector[j];
               vector[j] = aux;
            }
         }
      }
   }

   //método para mostrar el arreglo o vector
   public void mostrar(){
      //ciclo foreach para recorrer el vector e imprimir la posición
      for(String a : vector){
         System.out.println(a);
      }
   }
}
```

esto también lo puedes encontrar en Youtube, hay bastantes videotutoriales

Saludos cordiales,

Comment: El usuario está preguntando acerca de un error que tiene en un if (hace falta que explique más). Tu respuesta, aunque ordene el array, no resuelve para nada la duda del usuario que ha realizado la pregunta. Puedes leer [answer] para ver como hacer respuestas de calidad. Saludos.

Comment: Gracias @PabloSimonDiEstefano, ya edité mi respuesta indicando en el IF qué debe de utilizar para hacer una mejor comparación. Saludos

Answer (score 0):

No estoy seguro a lo que te refieres, espero puedas ser mas claro, de igual modo aquí te dejo un ejemplo de ordenamiento (Se ordena considerando solo la primera letra del nombre):

```
String [] nombres = {"Zack","Isaac","Ulises","Eduardo","Alejandro"};
    /* 
        Para realizar una comparacion de un elemento con todos los demas 
        elementos de un array se utiliza doble for tambien conocido
        como:  "Metodo burbuja" (no recomendable para el procesamiento de
                grandes sifras de datos).
    */
    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < nombres.length; j++) {
           String temporal;
           if(nombres [i].charAt(0)<nombres[j].charAt(0)){ //Recorremos los menores a la izquierda 
               temporal = nombres[i];
               nombres[i] = nombres[j];
               nombres[j] = temporal;
           }
        }
    }
    // Comprobacion de ordenamiento
    for (int i = 0; i < nombres.length; i++) {
        System.out.println(nombres[i]);
    }
```

Answer (score 0):

Claro, porque para saber si un String es menor, mayor o igual a otro debes utilizar el método compareTo que implementa String de la interfaz Comparable.